# Are type I error & FWER both conditional probabilities?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors, familywise-error

According to my textbook, type I error is defined as the conditional probability of rejecting $H_0$ given $H_0$ is correct. On the other hand, when I study the FWER (although the definition is related to type I errors), it seems like people are not emphasizing the conditional probability anymore.

```
H0  true    U   V  m0
H0  false   W   S  m−m0
  total     m−R R  m
```

FWER is defined as $P(V\ge 1)$, that is $P($reject at least one $H_0$, and that $H_0$ is true$)$.

Is my understanding correct?

And FWER is conditional on what? given all the null hypotheses in the family are true?

Comment: Anything like error rate must be conditional, because it's only an error if $H0$ is actually true. If $H0$ is false, there's no error.

Comment: Let;s say we have a family of tests: H1,H2,...Hm, so the FWER is P(reject at least one null hypothesis | H1, ...Hm are true)?

Answer (score 1):

In a Bayesian framework, these could be defined as conditional probabilities. But significance testing makes even less sense than usual in a Bayesian framework, so significance testing is rarely done in a Bayesian fashion. Instead we use a frequentist framework, in which conditioning a random event on a statement about population parameters is pointless. $H_0$ is not random; it's either definitely true or definitely false. So, $p(A | H_0) = p(A)$ for any event $A$, and the type-I error rate and the familywise error rate are not conditional probabilities, but marginal probabilities that are only correct if a certain condition holds. If in fact the condition fails, the probability no longer need be correct.

Admittedly, this an angels-dancing-on-the-head-of-a-pin issue and has little relevance for everyday data analysis.